# How to create a parent content type which consists of other child content types?

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to create custom content type (parent) which consists of other custom content types (children). Is this feasible in Drupal 8? Or I should do it programmatically?

Example: I want to have custom content type called ***Task***, and another custom content type called ***Subtask***. When a user creates a task, the user has to complete some fields (id, name), and should then create some *Subtasks* which are children of this *Task*. For the subtask some fields are to be completed also. In the end, each task will have some data such as:

- name = "task_one".
- description = "this task should do ..".
- subtasks = {"subtask_one","subtask_two"}.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, it sounds like you are describing reference fields. You would want to:

1. Create your two content types
2. Add a reference field to one of them. The refence field would be of the type 'content'.
3. (Optional, but probably) Limit the types of content that can be referenced to only the other content type.